# Free software for simulating the dispersion of air pollution

Tags: air-pollution, software, simulation

My team developed a method to detect PM2.5 hotspots in a city using mobile sensor measurements. Now, we want to simulate a validation dataset to test our method. We want simulated data so that we can set a 'ground truth' for where hotspots are located, and thus compute accuracy metrics.

Does anyone know a free software for this? I imagine it takes pollution source locations, wind speed, etc. as inputs, then outputs a time series of pollution values in a defined region.

**Already tried:**

- [Polyphemus](https://cerea.enpc.fr/polyphemus/index.html): looks good, but apparently the software packages have not been updated in 13 years
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_atmospheric_dispersion_models): has a list of atmospheric dispersion models, but it is unclear which are readily available as software

Comment: Depending on the level of complexity you need, you might try HYSPLIT or AERMOD.  If you are looking for multi-source complex models, CAMx and CMAQ are available.  Also, there is GEOS-CHEM and WRF-CHEM.

Comment: https://www.epa.gov/moves

Answer (score 1):

In addition to those listed in @f.thorpe's comment (I want to at least point to him to give credit for his choices, which are my first choices too), some other readily available models include:

- [ALOHA](https://www.epa.gov/cameo/aloha-software)
- [A bunch of alternative EPA models.](https://www.epa.gov/scram/air-quality-dispersion-modeling-alternative-models)
- [FLEXPART](https://www.flexpart.eu/)
- [CALPUFF](https://src.com/)